# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects Need help fixing

Tags: python-3.x

Well this is my first time using python and I don't know how to fix this problem.

```
ItemName = 0.0
Pounds = 0.0
Ounces = 0.0
Unit_Price = 0.0
Pound_Price = 0.0
Total_Price = 0.0

ItemName = raw_input("Enter ItemName")
Pounds = int(input("Enter amount of Pounds"))
Ounces = int(input("Enter amuont of Ounces"))
Pound_Price = int(input("Enter Pound_Price"))
Unit_Price = int(input("Enter Unit_Price"))

Total_Price = Pound_Price * (Pounds + Ounces / 16)

print("Item name is: " + ItemName)
print("Your Unit price is: $" + Unit_Price)
print("Your Total Comes To: $" + Total_Price)
```

when I put everything down it gives me type error.

Comment: @Yugo Did you read the error? It says, "Cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects". If that is confusing concatenate means put together (usually with a + sign), 'str' is a string such as "Item name" and int is a number. If you wanted to know what you were doing wrong, you could have just read the error. You were concatenating a string and int object, but python doesn't let you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.format` instead:

```
print("Item name is: {0}".format(ItemName))
print("Your Unit price is: ${0}".format(Unit_Price))
print("Your Total Comes To: ${0}".format(Total_Price))
```